# What is the procedure to apply for Canadian visitor visa for parents from Canada?

Tags: visa, canada, indian-citizens

I am currently in Canada on a Work permit. I am planning to apply for my parents visitor visa to Canada. Currently my parents are in Mumbai, India.

Can I apply for my parents visa **from Canada** without involving an agent? Do I need a sponsor letter and should it be notarized?

Comment: 1) Yes you can. 2) You need a letter of invitation inviting your parents to Canada. Your parents will put this letter when they apply for their visa. Details can be found [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/guides/5256ETOC.asp)

Comment: @DipenShah don't the parents need to apply for their own visas in India?

Comment: @phoog yup that's what I said.

Comment: @DipenShah but you appear to have said "yes you can" in response to the question "can I apply for my parents' visa from Canada," when the answer appears to be "no" because the parents must apply themselves in India.

Comment: @phoog sorry if I was misunderstood but in my second point I do mention that parents need to apply "for their visa". I meant in general the applier (you) can apply for the visa and doesn't need an agent to do that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about short-term visas.